# AndroidTv, Adding channels from an XML issue(samleTvApp)

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm having this issue with Android TV (sampleApp).

I'm inputting streaming channels from a xml file. I'm creating a temp file to be used at the start, and then I have created a button that does all the necessary functions to acquire data from the server and create the NEW xml file from that data. All of this works, but there's one issues:

After pressing the button and file is created, I try to add channels by pressing "add channels" button, but the file that is used is the temp file, not the NEW xml file. So that it uses the NEW xml file, I have to re-run the setup again and then it works flawlesly. It seems like it caches the temp file in memory or something and uses it first when adding channels, because when the app is launched there is no internal storage file (this is where i save my NEW xml file), the file is created only after the button press.

How do I make it so it uses the NEW xml file instead of the temp file(that created during app launch)?, instead of doing a re-setup

Comment: could you post a code snippet of your app that deals with XML files?

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that is used. Basically, on the first launch it creates an xml with no channels or programs(the temp file) and does what it has to. Then using my other class I create a NEW xml file with all the channels and programs. That also works, the file exists and it goes to the else statement after I press the "add Channels" button. But regardless, on the first try after pressing the button it always adds the temp file, rather than the new one. The new one is only runned, if I launch the setup again.

```
     public static XmlTvParser.TvListing getRichTvListings(Context context) {
        context1 = context;
        FileOutputStream fos;

        try {
            Boolean exists = context.getFileStreamPath(FILENAME).exists();
            if (exists == false){
                String string = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
                        "<!DOCTYPE tv SYSTEM \"xmltv.dtd\">\n" +
                        "\n" +
                        "<tv>\n" +
                        "</tv>";

                Log.d(TAG,"Exists: FALSE");
                fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(string.getBytes());
                fos.close();

                read = "file:" + context.getFilesDir().toString() + "/" + FILENAME ;

                Uri catalogUri =Uri.parse(read);

                if (sSampleTvListing != null) {
                    return sSampleTvListing;
                }

                try (InputStream inputStream = getInputStream(context, catalogUri)) {
                    sSampleTvListing = XmlTvParser.parse(inputStream);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error in fetching " + catalogUri, e);
                }

            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG,"Exists: TRUE");
                FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(FILENAME2);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int inputChar;
                while((inputChar = fis.read()) != -1) {
                    builder.append((char) inputChar);
                }
                String readFile = builder.toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "FileContent: " + readFile);

                read = "file:" + context.getFilesDir().toString() + "/" + FILENAME2 ;

                Uri catalogUri =Uri.parse(read);

                if (sSampleTvListing != null) {
                    return sSampleTvListing;
                }

                try (InputStream inputStream = getInputStream(context, catalogUri)) {
                    sSampleTvListing = XmlTvParser.parse(inputStream);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error in fetching " + catalogUri, e);
                }

            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return sSampleTvListing;
    }
```

The the button functionalities are in my richSetupFragment class(I wont post all of it, but these are the part that I think are most important in this case):

```
  @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Uri... params) {

            mTvListing = RichFeedUtil.getRichTvListings(getActivity());
            mPoster = fetchPoster();
            return true;
        }

@Override
                public void onActionClicked(Action action) {
                    if (action.getId() == ACTION_ADD_CHANNELS) {
                        setupChannels(mInputId);
                    } else if (action.getId() == ACTION_CANCEL) {
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                    else if (action.getId() == RETRIEVE_DATA) {

                        getChannelsFromServer();

                       // Log.d(TAG,"List: " + list);
                    }
private void setupChannels(String inputId) {

        inputIdLocal= inputId;
        if (mTvListing == null) {
            onError(R.string.feed_error_message);
            return;
        }
        TvContractUtils.updateChannels(getActivity(), inputId, mTvListing.channels);
        SyncUtils.setUpPeriodicSync(getActivity(), inputId);
        SyncUtils.requestSync(inputId, true);
        mSyncRequested = true;
        // Watch for sync state changes
        if (mSyncObserverHandle == null) {
            final int mask = ContentResolver.SYNC_OBSERVER_TYPE_PENDING |
                    ContentResolver.SYNC_OBSERVER_TYPE_ACTIVE;
            mSyncObserverHandle = ContentResolver.addStatusChangeListener(mask,
                    mSyncStatusObserver);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the issue related to permissions? Does `FILENAME` exist after you close the app?